# Images registration for low resolution highway images

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv with Python and I have a collection of images of highways. They have fixed resolution 352*288. They have been taken by mounted cameras, these cameras rotated horizontally and diagonally. I want to align this highways into piles,

I have tried feature passed images registration using SIFT, SURF and ORB. They are providing good results but when the image have rotation diagonally and when there is a small zooming the aligning will be damaged.

I have tried intensity based image registration using findTransformEcc and it is a little bit acceptable, but when I tried intensity based image registration using Matlab the results are much better.

example of images:
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r5y6.jpg)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW5OM.jpg)